# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 22): ReferenceError: client is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, try-catch

This error seems to be coming up on every `http` request I make. I'm not totally sure where it's coming from?

`(node:39390) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 22): ReferenceError: client is not defined`

There is no line number in the error, but here is a sample of code that seems to be causing it:

```
try {
    var client = await pool.connect();
    await client.query(queryStatement, queryArgumentsArray);
    res.sendStatus(200);
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error adding updating subvendor availability data, UPDATE SQL query task', err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
} finally {
    client && client.release && client.release();
}
```

It first I thought it must be coming from my finally block (maybe `client` was out of scope), but I added and if statement to explicitly prevent attempting to call `client.release` if it doesn't exist:

```
if (client) { client && client.release && client.release() };
```

I am still getting this error, so I feel like it must be coming from these lines.

```
var client = await pool.connect();
await client.query(queryStatement, queryArgumentsArray);
res.sendStatus(200);
```

Am I misunderstanding how to use async? To be clear, the code is functioning well and the `http` requests are working (responding correctly to the requests), my terminal is just getting flooded with these warnings.

Here is a simplified version of the full route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pool = require('../modules/pg-pool'); // brings in pg-pool created in another module

// This route updates the availability for a user
router.put('/updateAvailability', async (req, res) => {
    var userId = req.decodedToken.userSQLId;
    var subvendorId = req.headers.subvendor_id;
    var availability = req.body;

    var queryStatement = 'UPDATE status SET status=$3 WHERE userId=$2';
    var queryArgumentsArray = [availability.status, userId ];

    try {
        var client = await pool.connect();
        await client.query(queryStatement, queryArgumentsArray);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error updating subvendor availability data, UPDATE SQL query task', err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    } finally {
        client && client.release && client.release();
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Is there no line number in the exception?

Comment: That code looks fine. Is this the exact, whole code? Are you using the term `client` anywhere else (grep for it)?

Comment: @Bergi Correct, there is no line number. I updated with the full route (I simplified the query a little because it's not the focus). Any clues from here?

Comment: @LukeSchlangen try [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) instead. If you no longer see the issue, then the problem is inside the `node-postgres` driver.

Comment: This is really weird. How are you using ES8 `async`/`await`, with a transpiler or the native one? If the former, maybe we should have a look at the transpilation output.

Comment: Native node.js, so I don't have transpilation output. Specifically node v7.9.0

Comment: Hm, especially then I'd expect a better stack trace. Do you have a `process.onunhandledrejection` handler? Try inspecting the error more closely. Alternatively, file a bug with node (or two bugs: one about the unhelpful error message, another about the non-working script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credit here goes to `brianc` the creator of `node-postgres` who answered my question here after I received the suggestion that it might be a problem with that library (doesn't seem like it was). I simply needed create the client outside of the `try-catch`

```
var client = await pool.connect()
try {
  await client.query(...)
  res.sendStatus(200)
} catch { ...} 
finally {

}
```

His full answer can be found here: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1301